# Jquery function show not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My **script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#image_display').show();
   }};
});
```

My **main html page**

```
<input type="button" value="1" id="btn1"/>
<input type="button" value="2" id="btn"/>
<input type="button" value="3" id="btn"/>
<img src="img/book-cover" border="0" width="900" 
  height="300" alt="image1" target="_self" id="image_display"/>
```

What is wrong is that the show function is not working. I have tried all possibilities given in w3schools.com but still it is not working.

Comment: `id` should be unique, use `class` instead

Comment: did you include jQuery in your page

Comment: any error message you your browser console

Comment: as the below answers points out id of an element must be unique in a page.... but still if you click on the first element with the id `btn`(in this case button with value 2) it should work

Comment: if you have same both button then use class instead of Id, btn.

Comment: Failed to load resource file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/calendar/img/book-cover
Failed to load resource file://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5
GET file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/calendar/images/ajax-loader.gif                  This is the error it is showing in the console and i cannot figure it out

Comment: this error has nothing common with your question. i guess your import of the font is wrong since you haven't specified "http://" and you developing locally

Comment: yes it is running on a local host and there was no problem developing a page connecting to this because there are no fonts involved

Answer (score 2):

Here's a JSBin showing a working example (I'm hiding an element rather than showing it and it's an h1 rather than an img but the principle is the same):

http://jsbin.com/sozokeya/3/

There is a syntax error in the JavaScript (fourth line should be }); rather than }};) and you also have to buttons with the same ID "btn".

Comment: I have made the necessary changes but still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

ID should be unique, you can't have 2 elements with the same ID:

```
<input type="button" value="2" id="btn"/>
<input type="button" value="3" id="btn"/>
```

Comment: i want to have both the buttons display the same image when they are clicked that is why both buttons have the same id.

Comment: use class instead of Id's

Comment: use `class` instead if you want to describe a set of elements, which should have same properties\behaviour. The rule "ID should be unique" is mandatory

Comment: Even after changing the id to class the problem persists

Comment: then have you changed `$('#btn')` to `$('.btn')`?

Answer (score 0):

Use **class** instead of **id**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
  $('#image_display').show();
  }};
});


<input type="button" value="1" id="btn1"/>
<input type="button" value="2" class="btn"/>
<input type="button" value="3" class="btn"/>
<img src="img/book-cover" border="0" width="900" 
  height="300" alt="image1" target="_self" id="image_display"/>
```

Comment: what a reason for `id="btn1"` ? :)

Comment: @eicto OP used `id=btn1` so I thought he may be using it for some purpose. :D

Answer (score 0):

The two button'ID repeat,try to modify one